# constexpr not working if the function is declared inside class scope

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, g++, constexpr

I am using g++4.8.0, which doesn't contain earlier `constexpr` bug. Thus below code works [fine](http://ideone.com/YkmUDJ):

```
constexpr int size() { return 5; }
int array[size()];

int main () {}
```

However, if I enclose both the variable inside a `class` as `static`, then it gives [compiler error](http://ideone.com/TdxVq0):

```
struct X {
  constexpr static int size() { return 5; }
  static const int array[size()]; 
};

int main () {}
```

Here is the error:

> error: size of array ‘array’ is not an integral constant-expression

Is it forbidden to use `constexpr` in such a way or yet another g++ bug?

Comment: I didn't find anything disallowing it after skimming through the standard.

Comment: Since a member function definition can refer to members not yet declared, if this were legal you could also do `constexpr static int size() { return sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array) + 1; }`...

Comment: This is [CWG1255](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1255) (and more recently [CWG2335](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2335)).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, it is ill-formed.  Here's why:

A `constexpr` function needs to be defined (not just declared) before being used in a constant expression.

So for example:

```
constexpr int f(); // declare f
constexpr int x = f(); // use f - ILLEGAL, f not defined
constexpr int f() { return 5; } // define f, too late
```

function definitions inside a class specifier (as well as initializers and default parameters) are essentially parsed in an order like they were defined outside the class.

So this:

```
struct X {
  constexpr static int size() { return 5; }
  static const int array[size()]; 
};
```

Is parsed in this order:

```
struct X {
   constexpr inline static int size(); // function body defered
   static const int array[size()];  // <--- POINT A
};

constexpr inline int X::size() { return 5; }
```

That is, parsing of function bodies are defered until after the class specifier.

The purpose of this deferral of function body parsing is so that function bodies can forward reference class members not yet declared at that point, and also so they can use their own class as a complete type:

```
struct X
{
    void f() { T t; /* OK */ }
    typedef int T;
};
```

Compared to at namespace scope:

```
void f() { T t; /* error, T not declared */ }
typedef int T;
```

At `POINT A`, the compiler doesn't have the definition of `size()` yet, so it can't call it.  For compile-time performance `constexpr` functions need to be defined ahead of their use in the translation unit before being called during compile, otherwise the compiler would have to make a multiple passes just to "link" constant expressions for evaluation.

Comment: You're more or less correct.  The formal answer is that the point of definition for the member function written inline is at the end of the class definition.  Except that I don't think the Standard ever actually comes out and says this.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The only way to implement that requirement is by defering parsing of the function bodies until after the class specifier.  You need name lookup in order to parse C++.  So basically you delimit function bodes, default arguments and initializers - parse the class specifier - and then parse the previously defered delimited items.

Comment: That's still an implementation detail. The actual rule is that the class is incomplete within its own definition. But there should be a rule prohibiting calling static member functions on an incomplete type (while allowing access to previously declared static data members) and I can't find one.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The only way to "call" a function inside a class specifier and outside of a function definition, default argument or initializer is through a constant expression, so therefore this can only apply to `constexpr` functions.

Comment: @BenVoigt: ...and I would assume this is why it isn't better documented, as `constexpr` functions are new.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation, but I believe this is more of a limitation in standard. For example if a global function is declared before its use and defined at the end of the file, in such case compiler gives the same error. Why can't compiler apply the same strategy to the `static` member as well. If it's defined as mentioned in my code, then allow it to be used, otherwise give error.

Comment: @iammilind: because functions that are defined inline inside a class specifier need to be able to use things that are not yet declared in that class specifier.  This is not the same at namespace scope.  At namespace scope the function body is parsed as part of the function definition as you would expect.  It is not a limitation of the standard, it is an unavoidable property of the C++ "single pass" compilation design.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently [it's not even a bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51080), because its status is `RESOLVED INVALID`, which means that the people behind GCC and that bugzilla, after reviewing the problem, don't think that this is a GCC bug.

I remind you on that page because there is also an answer for this behaviour in one of the related posts.

Comment: @chris it's not like that, the standard is saying something about how that struct should be written and why this gives you an error.

Comment: +1 for finding the exact example link. However what they discussed doesn't seems to be justifiable. If member methods can be declared and defined outside. Global functions also can be declared and defined later. If compiler can differentiate the later case as 'when to give error and when not', then why not for the former case?

Comment: @iammilind: To use a global `constexpr` function in a constant expression it must be defined (not just declared) above of its use in the translation unit.

Comment: I think it's a defect in the Standard.  It should come right out and say that class member functions aren't defined until the end of the class definition.  Instead, we have a rule that says the class is incomplete inside its own definition, but this doesn't explain why a static `constexpr` member function can be used while a static `constexpr` data member can.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It does say this of course.  See 3.3.7 Class Scope.

Comment: @user1131467: I see nothing in 3.3.7 that prevents referring to a static member function from inside its class.

Comment: And 3.3.2 allows looking up the name (which doesn't *necessarily* make it invokable or defined) anywhere after the point of declaration, and specifically even where the class is still incomplete (meaning, in the remainder of the class definition).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes but `constexpr` functions also have to be defined (not just declared) before being used in a constant expression.

Comment: @BenVoigt, you are right. This seems to be a defect in standard.

Comment: oops, my earlier comment should say that "a static `constexpr` member function *cannot* be *evaluated*, while a static `constexpr` data member can"

Comment: @BenVoigt: It's because parsing of the initializer of a static data member is not deferred (3.3.7.1 only refers to non-static data members), whereas the function body of a function member is.

Comment: @user1131467: We're in the "declarative region following the name's point of declaration" (see 3.3.2p5), so no need to fit into one of the exceptions.  There's no doubt that the member name is in scope here.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You're missing the point, to implement 3.3.7.1 and related requirements about inline member function bodies, default arguments and non-static data member initializers, they need to be deferred.  So for example `X::array` is in scope and complete for the function body of `X::size`. This is why it doesn't work, `size` isn't defined yet at the declaration of `array`.  I however agree with you that this consequence should be explicitly documented in the standard to avoid confusion if it isn't already.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to add that even though this may not be good practice and will restrict you to defining the class body in the same compilation unit that its declared, it's possible to force the compiler to compile the definition of the function bodies at the same point as its declaration by adding a redundant template parameter:

```
template <typename = void>
struct X {
   constexpr static int size() { return 5; }
   static const int array[size()]; 
};

int main()
{
    X<> x{};
    ...
}
```