# Static constexpr: why does it need to be templated?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

I have two structures `a` and `b`:

```
struct a {
    static constexpr int f() {
        return 1;
    }

    static constexpr int c = f();
};

template<int I>
struct b {
    static constexpr int f() {
        return I;
    }

    static constexpr int c = f();
};
```

`a` is obviously not working because `f` is considered to be not defined here. But why the hell `b` is valid?

Comment: Why is `a::f` considered incomplete?

Comment: @NicolBolas Not incomplete but not defined, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493652/constexpr-not-working-if-the-function-is-declared-inside-class-scope

Comment: This is interesting. I think the answer has to with the fact that template members are all first defined and only later instantiated. But finding relevant Standard quotes is proving tricky, and the whole thing brings up other questions...

Comment: This is another variant of core issue 2335.

Comment: can adding inline help in c++17 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about that but i think that the compiler will expand that template in this way (in the case that int I would be 1):

```
struct b {
    static constexpr int f();
    static const int c;
};

constexpr int b::f(){
    return 1;
};

const int b::c = f();
```

So it compiles because the call of b::f is done after its declaration

infact if you declare a in this way it will compile:

```
struct a {
    static constexpr int f();
    static const int c;
};

constexpr int a::f(){
    return 1;
};

const int a::c = f();
```

So the answer is that during compiling the compiler evaluates b::c as a const value and not constexpr.