# How to make a type alias depending on a compile-time constant within a class?

Tags: c++11

I want to write a class that makes use of numerical quadrature. The quadrature order defines the size of some containers that I will use. I would like to make a type alias for such containers and it has to depend on the quadrature order.

The following code shows my trials. It feels suboptimal in the sense that I have to repeat the order in the type alias definition:

```
#include <array>

class Quadrature
{
public:

        static constexpr unsigned int getOrder()
        {
                return 3;
        }

        // This line doesn't compile!
        //
        // using WeightsContainer = std::array<double, getOrder()>;
        //
        // g++ says "error: 'static constexpr unsigned int Quadrature::getOrder()'
        // called in a constant expression before its definition is complete"

        // This line compiles, but repeats the order. :-(
        using WeightsContainer = std::array<double, 3>;

private:

        WeightsContainer container;
};
```

One solution that I have found is introducing a template parameter `Order`. But actually I wanted to determine the quadrature order and introducing the template parameter would make it variable.

Is there a possibility to make the order a compile-time constant **and** use it within my type alias definition?

Edit:

For completeness, I could of course use a preprocessor define. But that feels old-fashioned. :-)

Edit 2:

Okay, I have found another possibility. I could add a function outside the class scope like this:

```
constexpr unsigned int order()
{
    return 3;
}
```

But that feels wrong, because this is a property of the class and therefore should be within class scope!

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493652/constexpr-not-working-if-the-function-is-declared-inside-class-scope)?

Comment: @Quentin - I have seen a similar post. My question is not whether or why this is illegal, but what a nice workaround would be!

Comment: @BenjaminBihler One thing you can do is just make it a member variable: `static constexpr unsigned int order = 3;`

Comment: @0x5453 - You are right, this is probably the best solution. I wonder why I haven't thought of it.

Comment: Assuming you need the function's scope for calculations, C++17 has `static constexpr auto getOrder = [] { return 3; };` or even `static constexpr unsigned int order = [] { return 3; }();`, but I'm afraid C++11 doens't have such luxuries.

Comment: @Quentin - Interesting. I wouldn't have thought of that. Actually I am using C++17, I have tagged the question with C++11 just because the `using` type alias has been introduced with C++11.

Comment: @0x5453 - I guess the most concise answer is your comment. Do you want to post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to move the value into a member variable:

```
class Quadrature
{
private:
        static constexpr unsigned int _order = 3;
public:
        static constexpr unsigned int getOrder()
        {
                return _order;
        }    
        using WeightsContainer = std::array<double, _order>;

        // ...
};
```

If you need more complicated computations instead of just `return 3`, under C++17 you can use a lambda as @Quentin mentioned:

```
class Quadrature
{
public:
        static constexpr auto getOrder = []()
        {
            return ...;
        };
        using WeightsContainer = std::array<double, getOrder()>;

        // ...
};
```

Otherwise, you will need to pull the function outside of class scope for reasons mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16493853/3282436).