# Is there a way to avoid constexpr function used in header file from entering global scope without extra namespace for it?

Tags: c++, header-files, constexpr

I have a header file with code simply looking like this:

```
constexpr uint32 GenTag(const char tag[5]) { ... }

class SomeClass
{
   static constexpr uint32 TAG1 = GenTag("smth");
   static constexpr uint32 TAG2 = GenTag("abcd");
};
//constexpr needed for switch-case statement
```

The problem is that function `GenTag()` belongs to global scope and I would like to avoid it if possible.

I wanted to declare it inside class but it is not possible with `constexpr` (explanation here: [constexpr not working if the function is declared inside class scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493652/constexpr-not-working-if-the-function-is-declared-inside-class-scope)).

Does c++ have anything like "undeclare" function at the end of the header (maybe some macro tricks)? Or any other options I missed? If no better ways exist I would probably go with extra (maybe excessive) namespace, but want to ask if there are any other ideas.

Comment: Do you really need `GenTag` in the header?  static class members need to be initialized outside of the class in the cpp file so you jut define `GenTag` in the cpp file so it doesn't exist in the header file.

Comment: Hi Nathan. It it not true for constexpr as they are defined only inline (so yes, I need it in header). I need constexpr instead of const here because it is used in switch-case statement. Probably need to add it to question

Comment: What's the problem here, really? It's not like those multiple definitions are a problem.

Comment: Hi StoryTeller. I care about it cause there may be other functions accepting const char array with the same name GenTag, that function has specific versions for multiple classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to "undeclare" a function or variable in C++ (header file or not -- a header file is just included into the current translation unit). You'll need to use a namespace, or make `GenTag` into a macro. You *can* undefine macros with `#undef MACRONAME`.

Answer (score 2):

What about defining `GenTag()` as a `static constexpr` method in an inherited struct?

If you want that `GenTag()` is usable only inside `SomeClass`, you can make it `private` and define `SomeClass` as `friend` inside the class containing `GenTag()`.

I mean... something as follows

```
#include <iostream>

struct SomeClass;

class foo
 {
   static constexpr char GenTag(const char tag[5])
    { return tag[0]; }

   friend SomeClass;
 };

struct SomeClass : public foo
 {
   static constexpr char TAG1 = GenTag("smth");
   static constexpr char TAG2 = GenTag("abcd");
 };

int main()
 {
   std::cout << "Tag1: " << SomeClass::TAG1 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Tag2: " << SomeClass::TAG2 << std::endl;

   // compilation error: 'GenTag' is a private member of 'foo'
   // static constexpr char TAG3 = foo::GenTag("wxyz");
 }
```

With the `friend` trick, you don't need to inherit from `foo`; but, without inheritance, you have to use it as `foo::GetTag()`.

Comment: I thought it will work at first as in case of visual studio intellisence accepted that trick. But compiler did not. The problem is the same as in link provided in the question, the definition of foo::GetTag() will be processed only after it is used in TAG1 = ... declaration-definitions. Definitely an interesting idea, but if I am not mistaken it won't work. In both cases thank you, it was a good experiment to try

Comment: @Andrew - Interesting. And if you inherit `foo` from `SomeClass`, you get the same error?

Comment: max66 Did not tested it but almost sure that yes cause compiler processes definitions of any class methods only after processing all declarations (even if they are inline), no matter in which inheritance order it comes. But constexpr can be only inline defined and that is the reson my problem appeared - it is impossible to use any in-class defined constexpr anywhere else but implementation part (i.e. .cpp file)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever will also meet a problem like this I would recommend you to not use such constexpr in header at all but consider to declare-define it directly in and only in cpp file instead. Then you will definitely avoid unnecessary global scope pollution.

Or if there are multiple places where such constants can be used then make a separate heared for them without any classes and include that file separately from including class definition header.